# fgets function returning wrong value

Tags: c, file

My file has first line as below:

```
AXX00.data
```

But when I call below function, it stores XX00.data in ll

```
fgets(ll,10,keysFile);
```

Why this weird thing is happening? Kindly check the code below. But actually whole code would probably confuse you that's why I didn't keep it before, but to remove some confusion I am editing my question with code.

.... Putting complete code on request.....

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <unistd.h>

    int N=192;
    int L=8;
    int S[192];
    int i,j;
    int K[8];
    int X,Y;
    int KeyCounter[192];    
    int FMSAttack(int,int,int,int,int, int);
    int FMS(char[], int);
    int Max(int[]);
    /*void KSA(int *, int);
    KSA(int *S,int N)
    {
        it i,j;
        for(i=0;i<B+3;i++)
        {

        }
    }*/
    int main()
    {
        int i,j,B=0,nextKey;
        for(B=0; B<5;B++)//(L-3);B++)
        {
            /*int SCurr[N];
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                SCurr[i]=S[i];

            }*/
            for(i = 0;i<= 4; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j <= 9; j++)
                {
                    if(i==0 && j==9)
                        continue;

                    char fileName[10]="AXX";
                    char append[10];

                    sprintf(append, "%d", i);
                    strcat(fileName,append);


                    sprintf(append, "%d", j);
                    strcat(fileName,append);

                    strcat(fileName,".data");

                    //printf("%s\n", fileName);
                    nextKey=FMS(fileName,B);
                }
            }
            K[B+3]=nextKey;

            //KSA(SCurr[],N);
        }
    }

    int FMS(char fileName[], int B)
    {
        int f; 
        FILE *outfile;
        FILE *infile;
        FILE *keysFile;
        char outFileName[]="Out";
        char line[20];;
        char firstLine[20];
        char *firstLineArgs;
        char ll[10];
        int tuples;
        int count=0;
        int NextKey;
        int max;

        strcat(outFileName,fileName);

        infile=fopen(fileName,"r"); 
        //printf("%fopen\n",fopen("keysFile.data","r") );
        if(access( "keysFile.data",F_OK ) != -1 )
        {
            printf("a\n");
            keysFile=fopen("keysFile.data","a");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("w\n");
            keysFile=fopen("keysFile.data","w");
        }   

        fprintf(keysFile, "%s ",fileName);

        fgets(firstLine,20,infile);
        //printf("firstLine=%s\n",firstLine);

        L=atoi(strtok(firstLine," "));
        tuples=atoi(strtok(NULL," "));

        //printf("%d",L);
        //printf("%d",tuples);

        fgets(firstLine,20,infile);// To skip unnecessary line
        for(f=0;f<N;f++)
            KeyCounter[f]=0;    
        for (f=0;f<tuples;f++)                                              
        { 
            int k0,k1,k2,R;
            char *lineArgs;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
            fgets(line,20,infile);
            //printf("%s\n",line);
            //printf("%s\n",strtok(line," "));
            k0=atoi(strtok(line," "));
            k1=atoi(strtok(NULL," "));
            k2=atoi(strtok(NULL," "));
            R=atoi(strtok(NULL," "));

            if(FMSAttack(k0,k1,k2,R,L,B)==1)
                {
                    count++;
                    NextKey=R-j-S[B+3];
                    if(NextKey<0)
                        NextKey=NextKey+N;
                    else if(NextKey>(N-1))
                        NextKey=NextKey-N;
                    KeyCounter[NextKey]++;
                    //fprintf(outfile, "%d %d %d %d K[B+3]=%d\n", k0,k1,k2,R,NextKey);

    //              printf("%d NextKey=%d\n",count,NextKey);

                }

        }
        max=Max(KeyCounter);
        do
        {
                //printf("ll=%s\n",ll );
            fgets(ll,11,keysFile);
            printf("ll=%s fileName=%s\n",ll,fileName );
            if(strncmp(ll,fileName,8)>0)
                break;
        }
        while(fgets != '\0');
        printf("PRATIK\n");
        fprintf(keysFile, " %d\n",max);
        printf("PRATIK\n");
        fclose(infile);
        fclose(outfile); 
        fclose(keysFile);
        printf("PRATIK\n");
        return max;

    }
    int FMSAttack(int k0,int k1,int k2,int R,int L, int B)
        {
            //KSA

                // Assigning Initial Values
                K[0]=k0;
                K[1]=k1;
                K[2]=k2;

                //Initialization
                for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
                {
                    S[i]=i;
                }

                j=0;

                //Scrambling
                for (i=0; i<B+3; i++)
                {
                    int temp;

                    j=(j+S[i]+K[i % L]) % N;

                    //swap s[i] & s[j]
                    temp=S[i];
                    S[i]=S[j];
                    S[j]=temp;

                }
                X=S[1];
                Y=S[X];
                if(X+Y==B+3)
                    return 1;
                else
                    return 0;
    /*
            //PRGA

                //Initilization
                i=0;
                j=0;

                //Generation Loop

                for(i=0,j=0;i<3;i++)
                {
                    i=i+1;
                    j=j+S[i];
                    X=S[i];
                    Y=S[X];

                if(X+Y==B+3)
                    return 1;
                }
                return 0;*/
        }
    int Max(int KeyCounter[])
    {
        int i,max=0,totalCount=0;
        for(i=1;i<N;i++)
        {
            totalCount=totalCount+KeyCounter[i];
            if(KeyCounter[i]>KeyCounter[max])
                max=i;
        }
        printf("max=%d total=%d per=%d\n",KeyCounter[max],totalCount,KeyCounter[max]*100/totalCount );
        //if(KeyCounter[max]*100/totalCount>20)
            return max;
        //else
        //  return -1;
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to read anything from the file before calling `fgets`? Is you `ll` allocated and has at least 10 bytes of space?

Comment: The string you are reading is too long for the buffer, fgets reads n-1 chars and adds a null terminator at the end. Try `fgets(ll,11,keysFile);` instead.

Comment: @jpw: unlikely. What would then cause discarding the *first* byte? A too-short buffer may cause UB, but I don't think it would appear this way. (For a reasonably behavior of UB, at least.)

Comment: @Jongware Yeah, you're right, I'm tired. It should drop the last char, not the first.

Comment: Are you doing any calls to getc or getchar just before the fgets call? In any case you need to read 11 chars if you want the full string.

Comment: @user253900: unless you show more of your code, there is not enough information in the question to suggest an answer. That is reason to vote for a close.

Comment: No I didn't read before anything. Also I tried replacing 10 with 11. Didn't work.

Comment: Post a complete program that gives the problem

Comment: @user253900: Your file seams not to be open for reading but you try to read from it.

Comment: No it's even printing value of ll

Comment: @user253900: It is printing but the value is wrong. In order to open file for reading and writing, you should use `a+`/`w+` instead of `a`/`w` modes when opening the file.

Comment: Please see. I have already used it in if else loop

Comment: Do we really need 200+ lines to reproduce this problem? Some redflags: `keysFile=fopen("keysFile.data","a");` or `keysFile=fopen("keysFile.data","w");`, and  `char ll[10];` with `gets(ll,11,keysFile);`.  And why use a variable name like `ll`?

Comment: Another red flag: you're concatenating too much data into `char fileName[10]="AXX";` and overflowing that buffer.

Comment: See these codes are necessity for me, please just help me where I am stuck. I am already dealing with millions of data . . .This ll is temporary name I kept for testing.

Comment: The extra code may be necessary for you, but it's an impediment to people who might try to help.  I think it's reasonable for you to try to scope the information in the question to just things that are relevant to the problem. Also it's not clear to me if you've tried to address the suggestions in the comments - ie., that the file needs to be opened for read access (I suspect that `fgets()` is returning an error that you're not checking for) and the buffer overruns that have been pointed out.

Comment: "This ll is temporary name I kept for testing." -- Testing what, our visual acuity? And *please* try to narrow down your program to something much smaller that exhibits the problem. Just start deleting chunks of code.

Comment: Your title says "fgets function returning wrong value", but you ignore the value it returns.

Comment: See , I am printing value of ll. That is what I want to test that what it returns .

Comment: @user253900: however, `fgets()` returns a value itself, and if that value is `NULL` then it has hit `EOF` or has encountered an error and the buffer will be unchanged or indeterminate.  I suspect that `fgets()` is encountering an error since the file object wasn't opened for reading; I think that problem has been pointed out before. It's pointless to look at the buffer in that case.

Answer (score 0):

At least `fgets()` usage is very wrong.

```
char ll[10];
...
do {
  //   .....v......  Wrong size
  fgets(ll, 11, keysFile);
  printf("ll=%s fileName=%s\n", ll, fileName);
  // 8 and > here look questionable too.        
  if (strncmp(ll, fileName, 8) > 0)
    break;
} while (fgets != '\0');
//   ....^...... this is not a call to fgets
```

Suggest the following

```
char ll[12];
...
while (fgets(ll, sizeof ll, keysFile) != NULL) {
  printf("ll='%s' fileName='%s'\n", ll, fileName);
  if (strncmp(ll, fileName, 8) > 0)
    break;
}
```

Comment: Not working :( I think nobody is able to answer this question, I should shut it down.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out mistake. Append(a) doesn't support Read(r) mode. So had to change with Read+Append (r+) mode. Thank You very much for giving your precious time.

Comment: If you don't check the value returned by the `fgets()` function, you've still got serious problems.